# Why am I getting a System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission error in my .NET Application?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, .net-3.5, text-to-speech

I am trying to develop a text-to-speech editor in .NET 3.5 using C#.
I encountered the following exception: `System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission`.

How to handle it?

Comment: What code is causing the exception.  It could be any number of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system is saying that there has been an attempt to do something that is not allowed according to the current policy.  More information is needed to give good advice here:

1) What is the full text of the exception message?  There are [a dozen or so situations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securitypermissionflag.aspx) that can cause a SecurityPermission so this is important.  Specifically, there is a flag field that indicates the exact nature of the security violation.

2) What is the environment?  Are the files stored locally, or on a network share?  Apps run from a network share have always been partial-trust prior to 3.5 SP1.  Do you have .NET 3.5 SP1 installed?

Comment: Message: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.
VS 2008, Local, .NET 3.5 SP1 not installed.

Comment: Ok, the infamous APTCA.  What to you see when you to "ToString" on the exception?  Here is more on APTCA:
http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2005/02/04/367390.aspx