# What are user permission with impersonation to write file at server path?

Tags: c#, filestream

I used the example below but i have still have exception :

**System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission** 
**Here below is presented diagnostic info for technical support personel:
Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib**

Admin said the user credential has full permission to read and write

```
IntPtr userToken = IntPtr.Zero; 
bool success = External.LogonUser( 
    "userID",  
    "domain.com",  
    "MyPassword",  
    (int) AdvApi32Utility.LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, //2 
    (int) AdvApi32Utility.LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, //0 
    out userToken); 

if (!success) 
{ 
    throw new SecurityException("Logon user failed"); 
} 

using (WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userToken)) 
{ 
    //Create a new GUID, extract the extension and create a new unique filename 
    string strFileGUID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(attachment.AttachmentFileName); 
    string tempfilename = strFileGUID  + extension;   

    string path = "ServerPath"; 

    //Open a filestream and write the contents of the file at server path 
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write ); 
    fs.Write(fileContent.Content, 0, fileContent.Content.Length); 
    fs.Flush(); 
    fs.Close(); 

}
```

Can you please help as I am stuck on this problem?

Comment: First of all `System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission` is a class not an exception.  Can you add all the exception info you can see.  Inner exception, stacktrace, and line number are all helpful.

Comment: Here below is presented diagnostic info for technical support personel

Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed. at VirusScanningPOC.VirusScan.Button3_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't quite provide the information we need.  Can you post a screenshot when the exception occurs?

Comment: Check this post if it applies to you >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552436/why-am-i-getting-a-system-security-permissions-securitypermission-error-in-my-n

Comment: yes its virus scanner just to write file at server path and antivirus will do it automatically

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not run as full trust or did not get correct .Net permissions to perform PInvoke or access local files. It has yet nothing to do with Windows user permissions. The linked question will get you started on .Net CAS - Code Access Security - [Why am I getting a System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission error in my .NET Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552436/why-am-i-getting-a-system-security-permissions-securitypermission-error-in-my-n).

One easy way to check is run your application locally on the machine in question for local drive - should get full trust and no longer getting CAS exceptions.

Comment: when we asked admin to modify web.config to include trust level tag they refused that and we got at the end solution at the following post : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19830/How-to-Access-Network-Files-using-asp-net